# can't pass post params to yii2 controller by xhr request

Tags: javascript, yii2

In a view of my project i'm doing an xhr request to a yii2 controller

The request is structured like this in my view

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', '$urlToController', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");                
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
     }
};

// Print on console first
console.log({ id: JSON.stringify($('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows')), _csrf : csrfToken}); 


xhr.send({ id: JSON.stringify($('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows')), _csrf : csrfToken}});
```

and this is my controller:

```
public function actionTargetController() {

    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {

            $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
            return $post; // Print $post 
        }
   }
}
```

When i try to send the data with `xhr.send()` i don't receive nothing in the yii2 controller and the response i get is always '[]' (empty array)

I've also tried to send data with the FormData Object but the result is the same.

Where am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance for all the help

PS:

_csrf param isn't pass either so i've disabled csrf validation in the beforeAction method.

Comment: It would be much easier to use `$.post()`. Why is this option bad? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the mime type and change the data that you post.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', '$urlToController', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // <------ other mime type               
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
     }
};

var params = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows')
    .map(function (value) { return "selectedRowIds[]=" + value;  }).join("&");

xhr.send("_csrf=" + csrfToken + (params ? "&" + params : ""));
```

Now you could get the posted data in the action with:

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post('selectedRowIds');
```

You get an array of integers.

You could use jQuery for this too, since you're using it already. Much easier:

```
var params = {selectedRowIds: $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows'), _csrf : csrfToken};
$.post('$urlToController', params).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```